# !important keyword not propagating to children with Bootstrap less mixin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less, mixins

Per the less documentation:

> Use the !important keyword after mixin call to mark all properties inherited by it as !important
>   [less docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-the-important-keyword)

I am using the `.make-{size}-column(@columns)` mixin included in the Bootstrap source.  However, the `!important` keyword doesn't propagate to the sub properties here.  Specifically, I want the `width` property to become important, but it is not getting compiled that way.  The compiler outputs everything else perfectly, just no `important` keyword.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Just make sure you use an up-to-date Less version.

Comment: I'm using 2.5.3 which, as of 12/7/15, is the latest.

Comment: I see. Then I suppose you need to report a bug in https://github.com/less/less.js/issues - with a [minimal example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.make-some-column()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20foo%3A%20bar%3B%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%40media%20(min-width%3A%20whatever)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20width%3A%2025%25%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnbaz%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.make-some-column()%20!important%3B%20%20%5Cn%7D%22%7D) to demostrate the issue.